# Oracle 10g enterprise edition Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection?

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle10g, windows-10

Hi All I m trying to connect with Oracle 10g enterprise edition(from windows 10)

Here is the code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class firstjdbc

{

public static void main(String args[])

throws Exception

{

DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());

String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1158:em";

String uname="student";

String pwd="abc";

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,uname,pwd);

System.out.println("****connected");

System.out.println("Connection is:"+con);

Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

System.out.println("statement is:"+stmt);

con.close();

}

}
```

and this is the error which is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at firstjdbc.main(firstjdbc.java:12)
```

Looking for help if anyone faces similar issue.

Comment: 1) The database service is not running. 2) It is not listening to port `1158`. 3) The instance is not called `em`. 4) Firewall is blocking access. --- FYI: The default *database* port is `1521`. Port `1158` is for the *console* (webapp).

Comment: Thank you changed the port number.@Andreas

Comment: Updated sentence with tag